# Set certain words to appear coloured in iterm2

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I am trying to get `iterm2` to print certain words coloured (or bold, or whatever) as I am typing them in the terminal. I thought that I can somehow instruct it to check in a dictionary and if it finds a certain word it should apply a pattern, like you can do using the example on their website:

```
printf '\e\[0;31mplain\n\e\[1;31mbold\n'\ '\e\[0;91mhighlight\n\e\[1;91mbold+highlight\n\e\[0m'
```

which outputs

[image]

Somehow I would like to mimic the `vim` behaviour in the terminal, but I only need several such words.

I've been looking through their documentation and for similar questions on the internet but I did not find any answer and I suspect it's not extremely straighforward to do.

Is there any way this is achievable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of output do you want to highlight? Just the commands you type? Then you should dig for your shell settings (bash, zsh, fish, etc.; fish [has syntax highlighting](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_syntax_highlighting) for commands, you can change it). If it's some kind of text editor or something, then you should dig for its syntax highlighting too.

Comment: I just want some words for the shell. For example if I type `git push origin master` I would like `git` and `push` to appear in green. I am using *iterm2* and the question was solely for *iterm*, if this is possible in any way using it.